# qcleanlooksstyle belongs to which QT += in Qt

Tags: qt

I am searching "QCleanlooksStyle" belongs to which "QT +=". please help, ive centos 6.4 and Qt 5.3.

```
 #include <QApplication>

 #include <QCleanlooksStyle>
 #include <QtWidgets>

 #include "buttonbox.h"

 int main( int argc, char **argv )
 {
     QApplication app( argc, argv );

     app.setStyle( new QCleanlooksStyle );

     ButtonBoxDialog dlg;
     dlg.show();

     return app.exec();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html#changes-to-qstyle):

> QMotifStyle, QPlastiqueStyle, QCleanlooksStyle, and QCDEStyle are
>   replaced with a new fusion style. If your application depends on any
>   of these removed styles, you can either use the qtstyleplugins project
>   to get these styles or update your application to use the new fusion
>   style. For more details about this change, see
>   https://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/.

So you must clone the project, compile it and install it:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtstyleplugins.git
cd qtstyleplugins/
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

Then you must set the style using the following (you should not modify the .pro):

```
app.setStyle("cleanlooks");
```

Comment: there is new error when compiling by "make":-
Project LOAD(): Feature qt_plugin cannot be found. what about this

Comment: @rahul How have you installed Qt? Have you used the centos native installer or not? try with: `/fullpath/of/qmake`

Comment: I installed Qt by offine setup downloaded  from official website.  i tried with full path but same result.